# Are there libraries similar to cleverhans for different types of classifiers?

Tags: machine-learning, python, classification, scikit-learn

I am seeking adversarial examples for classifiers (e.g. random forest, logistic regression, multilayer perceptron) that I've already trained (through scikit-learn). But I can't seem to find any existing libraries for this purpose. This could be a fun project for me to start, but before beginning to explore my naïveté, is there any literature/code on this topic that I should be considering?

Answer (score 1):

Try [foolbox](https://github.com/bethgelab/foolbox)

> Foolbox is a Python toolbox to create adversarial examples that fool neural networks. It requires Python, NumPy and SciPy.

Also, join the [google group](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!forum/cleverhans-dev) of cleverhans, it's really good. Plus Ian Goodfellow is there along with Nicolas Papernot.